# Hibernate @Version - hit database

Tags: java, hibernate

I use @version annotation to implement optimistic blocking but when i save object i need before save/update operation check in database which version has and then assign it to my object and save, am i right?

> 1. Create new object
> 2. Hit databse and assign db version to it
> 3. Save to db

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch05.html

Comment: Hibernate will do it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't manually mess with the version but let Hibernate handle it.

Normally it is like this:

- You load an entity from the DB, including its version
- You change some data in that entity
- Hibernate eventually flushes the changes and issues an update query that contains something like `update ... set version = :newVersion ... where version := expectedVersion` (`expectedVersion` is the version value that was read in step 1, `newVersion` is `expectedVersion + 1`) and checks whether the update happened or not.

Note that is you use update queries directly, that version checking doesn't happen as Hibernate can't/won't alter your query.

What would happen if you'd do what you suggested in your question, i.e. read the version from db, set it to the object and then write?

In case of a new object you'd not get any version and thus need to use some default value anyways (in that case you can let Hibernate provide that default value as well).

If you'd update an object you'd basically circumvent optimistic locking. Why?

Assume two threads/users named A and B read your object. Initially it has version 0 so both see that version. Now A updates the object and thus the version becomes 1. Now, if B would want to update the object as well (and note that it still sees the data associated with version 0) your suggestion would read the version only, set it to 1 and write. The write succeeds but you might end up with lost updates since the data in memory would not reflect any updates done by A.

If we let Hibernate handle the version on the other hand the update by B would result in `... where version = 0` but since A's update already changed the version to 1 nothing would be updated so Hibernate sees a row count of 0 and throws an `OptimisticLockException`.